# Passing a parameter to NAnt build script

Tags: nant, build-script, nantcontrib

This is my scenario:

I have a `build.bat` that holds:

```
call tools\nant-0.92\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:deploy.build %* -logfile:deploy_NAnt.log
```

Part of `deploy.build` holds:

```
<project 
    name="EdpClient" 
    basedir="." default="build" 
    xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.92/nantContrib.xsd">
        <!--INIT -->
        ...
        <property name="version" value="1.48.0.4" />
        ...
        <!--RELEVANT TARGET-->
        <target name="BuildProductionApplication" description="Build">
            <property 
                name="publishFolderParameter" 
                value="/p:PublishDir=${productionPublishFolder}" />
            <echo message="Building..." />  
            <exec 
                program="${msbuildExe}" 
                workingdir="." verbose="true">
                    <arg value="${projectFile}" />
                    <arg value="/target:Clean;Publish" />
                    <arg value="${publishFolderParameter}" />
                    <arg value="/property:ApplicationVersion=${version}" />
                    <arg value="/property:PublisherName=&quot;${publisherName}&quot;" />
            </exec>
            <echo message="Built" />
        </target>
    ...
</project>
```

Now my question is:

- How can i call `"build.bat -version 1.48.0.4"` and replace the param
  in my structure?
- If the `-version` param is not supplied the script should throw some
  sort of msg back in command line?

Thanks to all that help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send parameters into Nant task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335698/is-it-possible-to-send-parameters-into-nant-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i did it:

In `deploy.build` file i changed:

```
<property name="version" value="1.48.0.4" />
```

to:

```
<property name="version" value="${arg.version}" />
```

And this is how build.bat (batch) looks like now:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %1.==. GOTO ERROR
ECHO:BUILDING VERSION: %1 ...
CALL tools\nant-0.92\bin\nant.exe -buildfile:deploy.build -D:arg.version=%1 -logfile:deploy_NAnt.log
GOTO END
:ERROR
ECHO.
ECHO Please provide the version parameter (eg. "deploy 1.1.1.1")
ECHO.
GOTO END
:END
```

Now I can call `build 1.48.0.4` command.
It suits all my needs.